# Spring Roo: 'web mvc setup' fails with 'display name required'

Tags: spring-roo

I'm trying to follow the Spring Roo tutorial at:

```
http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html
```

I was able to create entities and pass integration tests.

But, when I move on to create controllers, the following command fails:

```
roo> web mvc setup
Created ROOT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring
Created ROOT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml
Undo create ROOT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml
Undo create ROOT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring
display name required
```

When I move on to the next Roo step, I get the following:

```
roo> web mvc all --package ~.web
Command 'web mvc all --package ~.web' was found but is not currently available (type      'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
```

Any ideas on how to fix these problems? Thank you.

Comment: Note, I was using Roo version 1.21. I switched to version 1.1.5 and the above commands work as intended.

Answer (score 3):

You can see on pom.xml in tag  (around line 8) must defined its name.
e.g

```
package com.linux.gg
```

Tags name (line 8) should be

```
  3     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  4     <groupId>com.linux.gg</groupId>
  5     <artifactId>gg</artifactId>
  6     <packaging>gg</packaging>
  7     <version>0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  8     <name>gg</name>
```

If you delete gg on line 8. It will has a error.

```
display name required
```

If this solution cann't to solves your problem. You can find some tag which missing value (e.g. name, display) and assign a name of last package directory to them. (as gg)

You can see some information about your problem from this.

http://git.springsource.org/roo/roo/commit/c6d1759768d828b67c86da0350079b22135a764f.html