# Spring Roo web mvc setup generates error globalsearch.java class doesn't exists or has been deleted

Tags: spring, roo

I am quite new to Spring, now trying out Roo. I am following documentation from http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/

I was able to create the entity classes and fields, perform tests as well. Now when I run

```
roo> web mvc setup
```

it creates a few files in \config, \validatin, \html\converter but then produces undo create ... for the same files & folders. At the end it says

> ERROR: GlobalSearch.java class doesn't exists or has been deleted.

I am running Windows 10 64 bit, STS 3.8 Release, Roo 2.0.0.M2, Maven 3.3.9, Jdk 1.8

Googling this as well as searching in StackOverflow gave just one slightly relevant result without resolution [Spring Roo: 'web mvc setup' fails with 'display name required'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552925/).

In fact I have been facing many issues, each step of the way and googling my way through, so it has been a very painful experience so far, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a separately downloaded roo (v 2)for this.
Alternatively I used STS and added roo (v 1.3.1RC1) extension thru Help>Dashboard and opened roo console in STS (Window>Show view>Roo shell), was able to run the commands for `mvc web setup` and `mvc web all --package ~.web` and generate required files!

But don't know why the separate roo console wouldn't work.

Thanks for all who viewed and tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create **DAO** layer:

```
repository jpa --all --package ~.repository
```

This will generate *GlobalSearch.java* in *repository* package.